# How can Stability days in renovate help to avoid updating to dependencies with bugs/

Tags: npm, dependencies, updates, renovate

I want to protect my project from updating dependencies to early to avoid some issues via renovate.

I came across the  minimumReleaseAge property, but not sure if really helps me.

I thinking about the following scenario.

I have sent

One of dependencies get an update with an issue which gets fixed after 2 day of releasing.

So having the minimumReleaseAge set to 3. Wouldn't my project update to the broken version after 3 days and then after 5 days to the fixed version?